# C++ Program to find common in two sets with 5 integers works but has an error when I try to detect if there is nothing in common instead of "None"

Tags: c++, arrays

The code is supposed to detect the common elements of two sets of 5, which it does but whenever there is nothing in common, for some reason it cannot detect it and output "None". What am I supposed to do? I've tried setc.empty() but it was also an error, and now I'm trying to make setc[0] equal to -727, a number that shouldn't be outputted anyways and yet there's still an error.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;


int main ()

{


int seta[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int setb[] = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};


cout << "Enter 5 numbers for Set A: " ;

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

cin >> seta[i];

}

cout <<endl << "Enter 5 numbers for Set B: ";


for(int i=0; i<5; i++){

cin >> setb[i];

}


int i, j, k=0, x, common;
int setc[0]=-727;
   for(i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
      for(j=0; j<5; j++)
      {
         if(seta[i]==setb[j])
         {
            common = 0;
            for(x=0; x<k; x++)
            {
               if(seta[i]==setb[x])
                  common++;
            }
            if(common==0)
            {
               setc[k] = seta[i];
               k++;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   if(setc[0]=-727)
      cout<< "None" << endl;
   else
      for(i=0; i<k; i++)
      cout << setc[i] << " " << endl;

   cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)?  Note that `int setc[0]=-727;` is an invalid initialization.  You've defined a zero-length array and initialized it without braces.  Your compiler should be experiencing a hernia at this point.  To be safe, your output array must be at least the size of the largest input array.

Comment: `int setc[0]=-727;` is not a valid array declaration.

Comment: *The code is supposed to detect the common elements of two sets of 5, which it does* -- No it doesn't.  If it worked, you wouldn't have an issue with the program.  That's like saying "my car works, but the brakes do not".

Comment: @paddy Do I just put braces? Something like this and will it work? Sorry I'm new to C++
int setc[0]=({-727});

Comment: @Shin BTW, the solution is around 4 or 5 lines of code using `std::sort` and `std::set_intersection`, no loops.

Comment: @Shin What if the user entered -727 in both seta and setb?  Your idea of setting `setc[0]` to -727 will not work.  You need to get rid of that approach and try a different approach.

Comment: `int setc[5];` and then test the value of `k` to know if it's empty or not.  Note that the _comparison_ operator is `==`, not `=` (the latter does assignment, regardless of whether you use it inside an if-statement or not).  So you would use `if (k == 0)` to test for empty.